# groupby in react native flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, reduce, react-native-flatlist

I'm using fetch and Flatlist for getting and showing json data from laravel rest api.my output of laravel api is like that

```
[
{"teacher": "alex","student":"roger","class":"6"}
{"teacher": "alex","student":"simmon","class":"6"}
{"teacher": "alexandra","student":"henry","class":"8"}
....
]
```

In react native i use fetch api to get data from laravel like that

```
fetch('http://11.1.1.1:8000/api/get_data/' {
      method: 'get',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({ record: responseJson.data})
 })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

in flatlist i show data like that

```
 <FlatList
          data={this.state.record}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index + ""}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.tableHeader}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          renderItem={ 
            ({item}) => (
              <Text>{item.data.student}</Text>
              <Text>{item.data.class}</Text>


            ) 
          }
        />
```

my output is like that

```
sr.no    student    class
1        roger      6
2        simmon     6
3        henry      8
```

But i want to group by teacher name and my desired output is like that

```
alex //teacher name
 sr.no    student    class
    1        roger      6
    2        simmon     6
alexendra //teacher name
 sr.no    student    class
    1        henry      8
```

Hou to use reduce function in flatlist to achieve that kind of output?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own function:

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(this.state.record, 'teacher'))
```

or you can use an external library such as lodash:

> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy